# Put AggregateResult in Map

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, map, aggregate

I'm trying to put my AggregateResult in a map so that I can reference it later in my code.

```
trigger NoOfLiveProducts on Account (after insert, after Delete, after update) {

    map<Id,Integer> count1 = new Map<Id,Integer>();

    AggregateResult[] curProdCount = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(CloseDate) date1 FROM Opportunity
                                       WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.new
                                    GROUP BY AccountId];
    AggregateResult[] liveMktplcCount = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(CloseDate) date2 FROM Opportunity
                                          WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.new
                                       GROUP BY AccountId];

    for(AggregateResult ar : curProdCount){
        count1.put((Id)ar.get('Id'), Integer(ar.get('date1')));
    }



}
```

But there's an error at line `count1.put((Id)ar.get('Id'), Integer(ar.get('date1')));`

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Integer(Object)

How can I add the Count to my map?

Comment: If you're willing to keep the entire "list" in memory, a slightly faster shortcut goes like this: `Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(CloseDate) date1 FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.new GROUP BY AccountId]);` This keeps you from having to iterate the results manually at some small expense of heap.

Comment: @sfdcfox That sounds good to me.

Comment: The "shortcut" only works *if* you alias one of your groupings by "Id" (case sensitive). It's a particularly useful construct if you can find a place to use it, but I've never seen in a manual anywhere, which is probably why more people don't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to an `Integer` instead, just like you do with `Id`:

```
count1.put((Id)ar.get('AccountId'), (Integer)ar.get('date1'));
```

Comment: @AlexS Also, your AccountId isn't aliased, so make sure you fix that as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox But you don't need to alias grouped fields? However I'm not sure what the value of `ar.get('Id')` would be...maybe the map key should be `AccountId`.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks so I just need to use `SELECT AccountId acctId1`?